# Would missing check valve make it seem like heat is always on?

Tags: hvac, boiler

We had an extra zone added to our hot water heating system.  The installer used a Taco 007-F5 circulator pump but did not install a check valve like the other zones have. I have verified the pump does turn on and off correctly but it feels like the heat is always on in that new zone.  Would this be because there is no check valve?

Comment: I had a HVAC specialist come in to take a look at the system.  He confirmed that without a check valve the heat will continue to circulate.  "That room must have been very hot"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there may be a thermal siphon feeding hot water to the new zone and a check valve could stop that flow.  but it really should be an anti-siphon valve, not a regular check valve. (anti siphon valves have increased back pressusre compared to regular check valves)